# iOS Framework receive Apple Push Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've got a custom built iOS framework that I'm looking to distribute to other developers. The catch is that I'd like my server to deliver Apple Push Notifications (APNS) to their app, however neither of us will have any control over the others' Apple Portal.

I'm looking to determine if this is a possibility but need some help brainstorming through it.

My thoughts:

- Deliver my CSR to the developer
- Have dev generate apple certificate via Apple Portal and return/upload to my service
- Use their .cert and my .p12 to create PEM
- Use PEM as usual to deliver push notifications (my framework would utilize the proper UIAppDelegate methods for registration)

Is this safe/secure to do? Am I delivering anything top secret by freely giving out the CSR? (I could have it behind a paywall if necessary to deter some prying eyes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to deliver your CSR to the app developer?

The app developer should create a push certificate for their app and send you the p12/PEM file with its password. That's all your server needs in order to send push notifications for their app.

If you misuse their certificate (for example, by sending their app spam notifications), they can revoke the certificate in order to block your server from sending more notifications.

Since apple recently changed their Certificates creation portal, it is now possible to create multiple certificates for the same application. This means that the app developer can have multiple providers sending notifications to their app, and assign each one of them a different push certificate. This will allow revoking the certificate of one provider without affecting the others.

Comment: I was always under the impression that the CSR came from the sending server, thus they would need my CSR to generate their Apple Cert. Is that not true?

Comment: @ScottBonAmi That's not true. The CSR comes from whoever creates the certificate (i.e. a developer of the iOS application). My company sends push notifications to applications of other companies. For that purpose we only needed to get from them the p12 file and the password.

Comment: Well darnit I've been wrong about a CSR all along. You've been immensely helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Urban Airship does exactly what you're describing you're trying to do; they're the "middle-man" so to speak and handle push notifications so the developer doesn't have to worry about it. They do multiple platforms, not just iOS. http://urbanairship.com

So it's safe depending on the level of security you've implemented for your server.

Comment: It makes sense for me to trust Urban AirShip with my CSR as they are providing a service, I didn't know if it was still safe to provide it to 'random' individuals. You're saying as long as they cannot gain access to my P12, PEM, or server this isn't an issue?

Comment: Urban Airship doesn't gain access to your server, you just upload your P12 to them and they send the push notifications out on your behalf.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I merely accepted @Eran's answer as it provided more detail and information. Sorry for any confusion.